# Creating button with chopped transparent corner

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a button with chopped corner, the only challange is to make that corner transparent, instead of background color of that corner.

Attached the exmple I am trying to achieve

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  padding:40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #aaaaaa;
}
.btn-border-tilt {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #07926D;
    padding: 16px 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-border-tilt:after {
    content: "";
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: #cccccc;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    bottom: -12px;
    transform: rotate(-132deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="btn-border-tilt">This is button</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that modifying the button's background - using `linear-gradient` from transparent to the specific color - is what you're looking for:

```css
background: linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 15px, #07926D 0px);
```

And in context:

```css
.wrapper {
  padding:40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #aaaaaa;
}
.btn-border-tilt {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 16px 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 15px, #07926D 0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="btn-border-tilt">This is button</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, I am in hurry so made this, You can change anything as per your need.

```css
.wrapper {
  padding:40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #aaaaaa;
}
.btn-border-tilt {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #07926D;
    padding: 16px 10px 16px 35px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-border-tilt:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 26px 0px 20px 20px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #07926D;
    right: -20px;
    top: 2px;
}

a.btn-border-tilt:before {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 0 60px 30px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #07926D;
    right: -4px;
    top: -15px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="btn-border-tilt">This is button</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this with `after` and `before` and changes padding for text center

```css
.wrapper {
  padding:40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #aaaaaa;
}
.btn-border-tilt {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #07926D;
    padding: 16px 12px 16px 30px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-border-tilt:before {
    content: "";
    width: 18px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #07926D;
    position: absolute;
    right: -18px;
    top: 0px;
}
.btn-border-tilt:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
     width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-top: 18px solid #07926D;
      border-right: 18px solid transparent;
    right: -18px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="btn-border-tilt">This is button</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a triangle at the bottom.

Reference: [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

```css
.wrapper {
  padding:40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #aaaaaa;
}
.btn-border-tilt {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #07926D;
    padding: 16px 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-border-tilt:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 12px solid #aaaaaa;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-top-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="btn-border-tilt">This is button</a>
</div>
```